# Opencart only show children categories

Tags: php, opencart

I am using Opencart 1.4.9.3 and have the left side module installed for categories.

I have 2 problems I hope someone can help with.

1. I only want to show the category left module on the search page
2. I only want to show the related children categories (no parents on the search page)

I have the default category code (nothing changed) and have tried a few things like changing some category_id settings but nothing works. It either removes all categories or shows all categories.

I basically want the category module to function like a refine search module. I have also looked at modules to buy but couldn't find any that work as I need.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide the mod on all pages except the search page, try adding this to `/catalog/controller/module/category.php` file just after the `function index()` on a new line

```
if(empty($this->request->get['route']) || $this->request->get['route'] != 'product/search') {
    return false;
}
```